# Help required in TinyMCE to save HTML of the Rich Text Editor without "<style>" tags

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I am new to TinyMCE. I wanted to customize the HTML generated by the Rich Text Editor (RTE) to be saved with tags without 'style' attribute.

For example, here is what I want to achieve:-
If i change the font of text in RTE to color red (#ff0000), the HTML generated is:-

```
<p><font style="color: #ff0000;">Some text to format</font></p>
```

But I want the HTML to be stored as :-

```
<p><font color="#ff0000">Some text to format</font></p>
```

I am aware that <font> tag is deprecated, but I need to render this HTML in a Flex application which supports naive HTML.

I tried the following configuration:-

```
inline_styles : true
```

I also tried setting it to false, just in case I was comprehending the semantic, opposite.
But no success so far.

Any pointers shall be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mangirish

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE tries to stay away from deprecated things *(at least it did when I was a little more engaged in it, many months ago)*, so you may expect a lot of troubles.

The option [inline_styles](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3ainline_styles) (when set to false) is expected to do what you want, so it may be a bug. You may ask about this problem on [their forums](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewforum.php?id=1). *(The main creator of TinyMCE, Spocke, is a friendly man, who often answers this type of questions.)* Just be sure to show them the *full* configuration you have.